# XSD Schema Parsing with XJC

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, xjc

I have been trying to parse xsd file to be able to generate jaxb files locally. To do that, I have used `xjc` command on linux without any options from command itself.

But even I used it very basically as:

`xjc SpaceSystem.xsd`

it gives an error as given below:

```
ogurdogan@ogurdogan:~/Documents/XTCE/XJC Test$ xjc SpaceSystem.xsd  parsing a schema... [ERROR] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "enumeration" must not contain the '<' character. line 4399 of file:/home/ogurdogan/Documents/XTCE/XJC%20Test/SpaceSystem.xsd
```

Error occurred definition can be seen below on line 11.

```xml
<simpleType name="ComparisonOperatorsType">
 <annotation>
  <documentation xml:lang="en">Operators to use when testing a boolean condition for a validity check</documentation>
 </annotation>
 <restriction base="string">
  <enumeration value="=="/>
  <enumeration value="!="/>
  <enumeration value="<"/>
  <enumeration value="<="/>
  <enumeration value=">"/>
  <enumeration value=">="/>
 </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Even the xsd schema I have been using is a very generic and formal one from [here](https://www.omg.org/spec/XTCE/20180204/SpaceSystem.xsd), it gives error as seen above. Since it is a default schema and *should not* be changed, I do not know what I need to do..

After some tyrings, I also tried to use options from `xjc` such as:

- -nv
- -extension

But the result was same..

What is the problem there?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your XSD is basically an XML file - in which the character `<` is not allowed and has to be escaped as `&lt;`.

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the source of the linked schema (e.g. view-source:https://www.omg.org/spec/XTCE/20180204/SpaceSystem.xsd in Chrome) at line 4397 and following I find

```
<simpleType name="ComparisonOperatorsType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation xml:lang="en">Operators to use when testing a boolean condition for a validity check</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="=="/>
        <enumeration value="!="/>
        <enumeration value="&lt;"/>
        <enumeration value="&lt;="/>
        <enumeration value=">"/>
        <enumeration value=">="/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

That is quite different from what you show, indeed any XML document can't have an unescaped `<` sign in attribute value.

I don't know `xjc` but I would guess it will not complain about the real schema you have linked to saved in its original form, someone might have mistakenly saved the browser's "pretty print" rendering with select all-> copy -> paste, that is known not to preserve the original markup.

Comment: Thank you. Then the problem is actually the xsd file itself.. What do you prefer to take properly that xsd file into local rather than just "copying and pasting" since it looks not the best practice.

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan, no, there is no problem with the XSD, just save it (e.g. if you have it loaded in a browser window of Chrome use right-click -> save as to save it to a local file. That local file will have well-formed markup (e.g. `<enumeration value="&lt;"/>`). I don't know if the tool you use (`xjc`) also just allows you to run against a HTTPS URI but you can of course try e.g. `xjc https://www.omg.org/spec/XTCE/20180204/SpaceSystem.xsd`. The problem is that the pretty printer browsers tend to use to render XML doesn't manage to show the original markup so that is why `&lt;` ends up as `<`.